# How much extra power is required for a stereoscopic 3D game?

Tags: 3d, requirements

If we use Cryengine 3 for game development and make the game 3D compatible. Because 3D sends out two pictures, will this mean that you need a computer with twice the "power"? So if you get 30 fps when playing normal you will need 60 fps for playing with 3D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes you will need to be outputting 60fps to have the effect of 30fps.

Comment: I'm confused about this answer being the "accepted" answer, given the two seemingly contradictory answers also here.

Comment: I don't know why this is the accepted answer, as it is factually incorrect.

Answer (score 16):

**You do not lose half your performance when turning on stereo 3d.** The games logic, AI, physics, and anything the CPU does still is only run once. Only the rendering is done twice, and that is efficient, because the card has everything in memory for what each second frame is going to be, so it doesn't use any additional bandwidth.

The only situation where this will be true is if you had a static 3d scene that was really complicated with the GPU doing everything and the CPU sitting idle. And even then I doubt it will be a 50% drop in performance

I have tested a lot of games with nvidia 3d stereo, and no game ever dropped near 50% performance.

Answer (score 9):

Especially with CryEngine 3 this is not true. Yes, it halves the framerate, but turning on 3D does not cost you half your frames (or you need doubled hardware power). They use a reprojection cache and the available depth buffer to get the second image, thus the performance drop is 5-10% when turning on 3D. They call this "Screen Space Re-Projection Stereo".

Comment: Yes but it is not full stereo.

Comment: They mention this on a game developer commentary somewhere, can't find the link at the moment.

Comment: @samboush: Why is this not "full stereo"? It works with Nvidia 3D Vision and usual Stereo Glasses.

Comment: @Enrico: If you have Screen with depth, you know real coordinates of every pixel. Then U can count shift of normal scene for left and right eye. But real 3D stereo is that you draw two scenes - firts for left eye  and second for right eye. Two full scenes. Then it takes 2 time more of drawing time.

Comment: Why do you want to completely re-draw every single with a slight offset for Stereo Rendering, when you already have these information? Most of the calculated pixels will be correct in the reprojection cache, no need to recompute them. Those that change are of course recomputed - et voila, you have complete stereo.

Comment: Screen Space Re-Projection Stereo can have artifacts.

If there is a brick wall, and you are looking at it exactly parallel to one face, the one eye should be able to see that face, while the other should not be able to. Also on a curved object, the right eye should see slightly more of the right side, and the left slightly more of the left. Both of these are impossible with single pass rendering with Screen Space Re-Projection.

Comment: @AttackingHoboYes: You are right and Good example. They use right eye first then caclulate left. My example is easy too. You have sheet of paper and looking on it abeam : on right side  You have letter "A" and on left side of paper you have letter "B" . On full stereo You will see "A"&"B" but in CryEngine3 You will see "A" only.

Comment: But they *do* two render passes and not one - they dont do one render pass and magically a 3D image pops out. They do render two full passes.

@AttackingHobo: A brick wall has six/eight sides, so which one is not visible? How do you know if that brick side is not visible?

There are some information from GDC, the best video describing and seeing this is here: http://www.golem.de/1008/77241.html - but its german...

Comment: Your description confused me, it sounded like you said they get the original image and use the depth data to make two images from that.

Answer (score 1):

I would say not negligible at all. It's both a hardware resource problem and a development challenge.

Most of the time you cannot split the framerate between the two eyes; if your game usually runs at 60fps, **you need to run at 120fps** for the same visual comfort.

However, a lot of things can be done only once per stereo pair: frustum culling -- at the cost of a slightly larger frustum (see *Setting up the 3D Cameras* in [Optimization for Making Stereoscopic 3D Games on PlayStation®](http://research.scee.net/files/presentations/nordic/OptimizationforMakingStereoscopic3DGamesonPlayStationPS3.pdf)), occlusion culling, vertex and index array uploads, scene captures and renders to texture...

Parts of the scene may be rendered only once: for instance, a complex sky with clouds, stars, etc. will usually be at infinity, so the pixel shader cost is only needed once, and the second rendering can be a mere texture lookup into the first render target. Actually some stereo games use a method called reprojection that builds on this approach to make it viable for the whole scene: see [this thread at beyond3d](http://forum.beyond3d.com/showthread.php?t=60716) for pointers to this technique.

To cope with the required extra processing power, you can reduce the resolution. From my personal experience, it is far more acceptable to do so than to reduce the framerate. Do not try to disable anti-aliasing, though: as Sony engineers say in the above paper, *rendering to lower resolution buffers with AA looks better than high resolution buffers with no AA*.

Note that there are other approaches to stereovision in games that don't need a 3D TV, such as [Trioviz](http://eu.trioviz.com/en). I cannot go into the details here, though (NDA issues).