# How much extra processing power is required for a 3D TV compatible game?

Tags: 3d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much extra power is required for a stereoscopic 3D game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/591/how-much-extra-power-is-required-for-a-stereoscopic-3d-game)

How much extra processing power would be required to make a 3D TV compatible mode in a 3D game?

(Nothing specific, think any modern FPS)

Would it be negligible as you would split the framerate between the two 'eyes'?

Comment: By 3D TV, do you mean stereoscopic rendering? I guess this is related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/591/cryengine-3-3d-double-requirement

Comment: That pretty much covers it, thanks - want to mark as duplicate or put in as answer and I'll mark it.